# Haskell parse error on input `<-'

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, functional-programming, compiler-errors, ghc

Can't seem to line up (indent) this code correctly in Haskell.
Getting error:

```
parse error on input `<-'
```

Can anyone spot where the error is at:

```
evalListSplitAt n stratPref stratSuff [] = return []
evalListSplitAt n stratPref stratSuff xs = do ys` <- stratPref ys
                                              zs` <- stratSuff zs
                                            return (ys` ++ zs`)
                                            where (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to indent every line in a `do` block equally. Also, make sure to use `'` for variable names rather than `` ` ``. (That is, use an apostrophe rather than a backtick. Backticks are used for making functions infix, so they cannot be used as part of a variable name. So you can name something "x prime" using an apostrophe: `x'`.) So your code should look something like this:

```
evalListSplitAt n stratPref stratSuff [] = return []
evalListSplitAt n stratPref stratSuff xs = do ys' <- stratPref ys
                                              zs' <- stratSuff zs
                                              return (ys' ++ zs')
                                        where (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs
```